# Flex 2 columns where one is fixed width and the other is width 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to divide my page into 2 columns. I want content on the left with a padding on it together with a border. On the right I want my sidebar, which has a fixed width.

https://jsfiddle.net/mortenmoulder/04fkrkpp/

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I have tried doing that, but I'm not sure if I should use `space-between` or something else. I have basically achieved what I want, but the padding should be equal on all the sides. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flex-grow:1;` instead of `width:100%;`, and you need to change of few other things as well

Use border directly on **#left-container** and add `margin` instead of `padding`, this will make the space equal to all sides.

[**See updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/codename0/04fkrkpp/2/)

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

#left-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 20px solid black;
  margin: 50px;
}

#left {
  height: 100%;
}

#right {
  width: 300px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-container">
    <div id="left">
      <p>
        Some content here
      </p>
      <p>
        Some content here
      </p>
      <p>
        Some content here
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <p>
      Right sidebar
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hell yeah, that did it. Thanks a lot, will mark as solved in ~5 minutes.

Comment: Cheers !! I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

check below code I just added `flex: 1` and remove some unnecessary code from your demo

```css
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    /*flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;*/
    height: 100%;
}

#left-container {
    padding: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
}

#left {
    border: 20px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    /*width: 100%;*/
}

#right {
    width: 300px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-container">
        <div id="left">
            <p>
                Some content here
            </p>
            <p>
                Some content here
            </p>
            <p>
                Some content here
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <p>
            Right sidebar
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/04fkrkpp/3/

Comment: Bottom doesn't really follow along. I'm using Chiller's answer and it works great.